# flex-compiler-oem.jar could not resolve <s:Application> to a component implementation

Tags: java, api, apache-flex

i am trying the hello world example found here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/CompilerAPI/flex_4.0_compilerapi.pdf

however, i keep getting the following error:

message = "Could not resolve  to a component implementation.
Path: /home/xxx/public_html/DSM10.mxml
Line: 1"

if i try the hello world example found here, it works fine:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/compilerAPI_flex3.pdf

i am running the hello world example on a LAMP stack using apache-tomcat-6.0.35.

here is my code:

```
String dirPublicHtml = dirPathApp + "/../../public_html";
String dirOutput = dirPublicHtml + "/outgoing"; 
File parent = new File(dirPublicHtml).getCanonicalFile();
VirtualLocalFileSystem fs = new VirtualLocalFileSystem();
File dsmFile = new File(parent, "DSM10.mxml");
```

"Hello World" from Flex 4 Compiler API documentation

```
VirtualLocalFile lf = fs.create(dsmFile.getCanonicalPath(), 
    "<?xml version='1.0'?> 
    <s:Application xmlns:fx='http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009'
    xmlns:s='library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark' 
    xmlns:mx='library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx'> 
    <s:Label text='Hello World'/> </s:Application>", parent, 
    System.currentTimeMillis());
```

"Hello World" from Flex 3 Compiler API

```
/*VirtualLocalFile lf = fs.create(dsmFile.getCanonicalPath(), 
    "<?xml version='1.0'?>
    <mx:Application xmlns:mx='http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml'>
    <mx:Label text='Hello World'/></mx:Application>", parent, 
    System.currentTimeMillis());*/

Application app = new Application(lf);
app.setLogger(logger);
app.setOutput(new File(dirOutput + "/DSM10.swf"));
long result = app.build(true);
lf.close();
if (result <= 0) throw new Exception(logger.getLogMessage());
```

Answer (score 1):

since i was running "hello world" on a web server i needed to upload the necessary flex sdk framework and library files. the previous sdk was 3.6. i had to upload v4.6. after i restarted apache-tomcat-6.0.35 the s:Application error went away and a new one popped up. so now i am onto fix it, i.e. upgrading the as3/flex code from sdk 3.6 to 4.6.